# Discord economy bot python withdraw command not working does somebody know why?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I'm making a bot in python for discord, which is an economy bot, it stores all of its data in a json file called "MainBank.json" everything works just fine except that one thing when you try to deposite your money in the bank or when you try to withdraw money from the bank. I do not see a problem with that.

```
@bot.command()
async def withdraw(ctx,amount = None):
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    if amount == None:
        await ctx.send("Please enter a valid amount!")
        return
  
    bal = await update_bank(ctx.author)

    amount = int(amount)
    if amount>bal[1]:
        await ctx.send("You don't have enough potatoes in your bank!")
        return
    if amount<0:
        await ctx.send("Please enter a valid amount!")
        return

        await update_bank(ctx.author,amount, "wallet")
        await update_bank(ctx.author,-1*amount, "bank")

        await ctx.send(f"You withdrew {amount} potatoes!")

@bot.command()
async def deposit(ctx,amount = None):
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    if amount == None:
        await ctx.send("Please enter a valid amount!")
        return
  
    bal = await update_bank(ctx.author)

    amount = int(amount)
    if amount>bal[0]:
        await ctx.send("You don't have enough potatoes in your wallet!")
        return
    if amount<0:
        await ctx.send("Please enter a valid amount!")
        return

        await update_bank(ctx.author, -1*amount)
        await update_bank(ctx.author, amount, "bank")

        await ctx.send(f"You deposited {amount} potatoes!")

async def open_account(user):

  users = await get_bank_data()

  if str(user.id) in users:
      return False
  else:
      users[str(user.id)] = {}
      users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
      users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0

  with open("MainBank.json", "w") as f:
      json.dump(users,f)
  return True

async def get_bank_data():
    with open("MainBank.json", "r") as f:
      users = json.load(f)

    return users



async def update_bank(user,change = 0,mode = "wallet"):
  users = await get_bank_data()

  users[str(user.id)][mode] += change

  with open("MainBank.json", "w") as f:
      json.dump(users,f)

  bal = [users[str(user.id)]["wallet"],users[str(user.id)]["bank"]]
  return bal
```

Comment: Please add your tracebkack after excuting the commands. Without any errors it is hard to tell where the problem might be.

Comment: I suspect you want to look at the `if amount<0`-section of your code. There are three lines after the return statement that should be moved out one indentation layer. As it stands, they are never being executed

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely have to pay attention to the correct indentation.
I noticed the following error with the `withdraw` command:

```py
    if amount<0:
        await ctx.send("Please enter a valid amount!")
        return

        await update_bank(ctx.author,amount, "wallet")
        await update_bank(ctx.author,-1*amount, "bank")

        await ctx.send(f"You withdrew {amount} potatoes!")
```

Your `await update_bank` and `await ctx.send` arguments have to be under the `if amount < 0:` statement:

```py
    if amount < 0:
        await ctx.send("**The amount must be positive.**")
        return
    await update_bank(ctx.author, amount)
    await update_bank(ctx.author, -1 * amount, "bank")

    await ctx.send(f"**You added {number_with_commas(amount)} coins to your wallet.**")
```

If you do not `await` the function correct it will not work. This is the same for the `deposit` command where you have not properly indented the code.